# Add a UIView into a ComposeViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIView and its nib. I also have a UIViewController along with its nib. I would like to add the UIView into the UIViewController. How do I do that?

Edit:
My original question wasn't clear enough as I didn't understand iOS well enough. Since now I do, what I wanted was to create a UIView subclass along with its nib that can be embedded in other UIView/UIViewControllers. The answers to given to the original question would definitely work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually multiple ways to create an embeddable UIView. Here's the approach I went with:

WidgetView is the UIVIew I want to embed into other UIView/UIController,

```
@interface WidgetView : UIView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@end


@implementation WidgetView
// This method gets called whenever you load a nib during runtime
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"WidgetView" bundle:nil];
        NSArray *views = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        [self addSubview:views[0]];
        self.label.text = @"Hell World.";
    }
    return self;
}
@end

//MyController.m
@interface MyController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WidgetView *customView;
@end

@implementation MyController
...
@end
```

Then in MyController.xib, drag a UIVIew into the nib, and set the CustomClass to be WidgetView and drag the outlet into MyController

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
@interface Controller {}
@property(retain) IBOutlet UIView *extraView;
@end

…

- (void) viewDidLoad // or anywhere else
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"extras" owner:self options:nil];
    NSAssert(extraView != nil, @"The extra view failed to load.");
    [[self view] addSubview:extraView];
}
```

or simply add the line [self.view addSubview:extraView]; to where you need if you already have named it

Edit:

```
NSArray *myNibsArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil];
Y *extraView= [myNibsArray objectAtIndex:0];
[[self view] addSubview:extraView];
```

Comment: What is extraView in the interface? Usually I drag a UIView from a X.xib into its own X.m file. In this case, I want to use another Y.xib in X.m file..

Comment: How do I define the extraView in the interface? Usually I have to drag it into the .m file. In this case, do I simply type out `@property(retain) IBOutlet UIView *extraView;`?

Comment: Also, how does it where in the controller's .xib to add the UIView?

Comment: for example,extraview.frame = CGRectMake(30, 50, 10, 10);

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:self options:nil];
Y *extraView= [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:extraView];
```